# HBM mapping image/binary

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am having trouble mapping our `byte[]` field. I've been looking for several solutions but none work so far. All I get is this exception:

> ```
> The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.
> ```

Below is what I've got so far in the `hbm.xml`

```
<property name="Data" type="BinaryBlob">
    <column name="attachmentData" sql-type="varbinary(max)"/>
</property>
```

Am I doing something not right here?

**Update - Solution:**

It turned out that I have done it incorrectly. We are inserting the `byte[]` via **stored procedure** so the property mapping has nothing to do with it. Instead, we need to tell NHibernate the type of the sprocs parameter like so:

```
query.SetParameter(param.Key, param.Value, NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob);
```

Comment: Please add the solution as an Answer and select it as the correct one, this way you're marking the Question as **Solved** ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't understand varbinary(max) and will use the default of 8000 bytes.

Therefore you will need to supply the number. I.e.

> varbinary(2147483647)

I think used to work but is a [regression](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2484) bug.

Comment: No it doesn't work too. I still get the same exception with file >8KB

Comment: Thanks Rippo for your answer and I guess it will work but I have corrected myself on the post. I had a different case and that was me doing the wrong thing :)